# how to specify trust store and trust store password in jTDS connection url?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, ssl, jdbc, jtds

I am writing one java application which connects to database with ssl connection using jTDS.
I have added the property ssl=require to the connection URL to enable ssl connection.

But I couldn't find how to configure the properties where I can specify which trust store to use and what is the password for it? All jTDS connection properties are listed here: http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html

SQL server jdbc driver has these kind of properties trustStore and trustStorePassword, per this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb879949.aspx

Any idea how to configure ssl connection using jTDS with these properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify the `trustStore` and `keyStore` location and their password dynamically through `Java application` as follow:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStore file path goes here);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", password goes here);

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStore file path goes here);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", password goes here);
```